# File size limit in Windows Phone application using C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am new in Windows Phone application. In my application, when uploading files it is required to add file size limit not exceeding 50kb.

**Code:**

```
public sealed class OpenFileDialog
{
    public string Filter { get; set; }

    internal static object ShowDialog()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public static object DialogResult { get; set; }
    public static string FileName { get; set; }
}

if (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Controls.DialogResult.OK)
{
    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(OpenFileDialog.FileName);
    if (fs.Length > 51200)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Image size must not exceed 50kb.");
        return;
    }
    System.Windows.Controls.Image myImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
    myImage.Source = bmp;
}
```

but it show error,

**Error:**

```
 namespace dialogresult doesn't exist in the namespace system.windows.controls(missing a assembly reference)
```

Anybody help me to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to use an enumeration that is part of the System.Windows.Forms namespace, and no such open file dialog exists in the Windows Phone 8 library. Without knowing more about your file access scenario, I will point out that your options would include:

- Application Isolated Storage
- Known Folders (WP 8.1 only including music, videos, photos, and SD card storage)

I'll point you to this [general guide to accessing files programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ150593(v=win.10).aspx) which may take you to where you need to be specifically, but I should point out that since the most commonly accessible files on a phone device are rarely 50kb or less in size, we likely need more information about your use case.

Comment: Is there any option for file dialog in windows phone 8??